# Returned variable is NULL

Tags: c, function, pointers

When I said: "Returned variable is NULL.", I meant that it returns a stuct that contains two pointers and `they == NULL`.

```
struct LandR_8
{
    unsigned char *L;    // For L channel.
    unsigned char *R;    // For R channel.
};                       // These pointers point to the allocated memory.
struct LandR_8 LRChannels_8;
```

My function:

```
struct LandR_8 sepChannels_8( unsigned char *smp, unsigned char *L, unsigned char *R, unsigned long N, struct LandR_8 LRChannels )
{
    int i;

    L = malloc(N / 2);
    R = malloc(N / 2);

    for ( i = 0; i < (N / 2) ; i++ )    // separating
    {
        L[i] = smp[2 * i + 0];
        R[i] = smp[2 * i + 1];
    }

    // L and R don't need `free()`.

    return LRChannels;
}
```

returns variable `LRChannels` of type `struct LandR`:

I call my function like so:

```
LRC_8 = sepChannels_8( ptrSamples_8, ptrSamples_8_L, ptrSamples_8_R, n, LRChannels_8 );
```

The problem is that after using that function `LRC_8.L == NULL`.

Why does it so?

Comment: You need to give some details of what `sepChannels_8` does (ie, code the function) to know why it returns `NULL`.

Comment: How about showing the code for sepChannels_8???

Comment: What's the code for `sepChannels_8`, and what are the arguments passed?

Comment: It seems that this is bery stupid problem... I'll look somewhere about it in order not to bore you.

Comment: Uhm... you aren't helping us help you. Imagine going to a mechanic and saying "my car makes a weird noise from the engine compartment. I brought you a picture of the windshield. What's the problem with my car?" Your questions must be clear and contain enough information for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @NikBougalis, I'll think about it for some time and then reAsk this question later if the problem remains.

Comment: @Julian Good luck - we will  be here if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @NikBougalis, I'm new to `stackoverflow`... Can you give me advise? Must I delete this question (because it doen't provide useful and interestion problem)? Or shall I edit it more and more?.. I think that the 2-nd way is better because I don't want to make a mess here...

Comment: @Julian Edit it to contain useful information. The best thing would be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Julian you can choose to "edit" your question (there's a small "edit" link you can use) to supply additional information or imporve the question, or you can choose to delete it. I think that after your edit, this question is better.

Comment: You never set LRChannels.L and LRChannels.R to anything.

Comment: LRChannels_8 is not initialized

Comment: @τεκ no, he set it here: `, struct LandR_8 LRChannels`

Comment: @kotlomoy That is not setting the values.

Comment: I don't understand how that is not a real question. It is absolutely clear what he wants and what is wrong here...

Comment: @glglgl It was "Not A Real Question" before the edit. I've voted to reopen, since now it is a real question.

Comment: @glglgl why? Here `, LRChannels_8` he passes argument by value and here `, struct LandR_8 LRChannels` he creates local variable and initializes it with value of passed argument

Comment: @kotlomoy Yes, but that setting doesn't happen inside the function, making it pointless.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, that's why I said "LRChannels_8 is not initialized"

Comment: @kotlomoy but you told @τεκ "no, he set it here: `, struct LandR_8 LRChannels`", but that doesn't count.

Comment: @glglgl Look, here `, struct LandR_8 LRChannels` means `struct LandR_8 LRChannels = LRChannels_8`. So, *syntaxically* setting does happen inside function. That's what I mean. What you mean is *logically* there's no setting here because LRChannels_8 not set. I agree. Now we stop this pointless discussion because there's no disagreement actually :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I succeeded to solve the problem (with your help)!

Comment: Can anyone tell me why after using function, when I look into the address of `LRC_8.L` and `LRC_8.R` I see: 00,00,00,00,00 and so on...
It seems that I have array of "zeros"..

Comment: That would probably be what was stored in `smp`.

Comment: No. Well, maybe, it's not forbidden. But generally, `malloc`ed memory is not initialised at all. However, when the OS gives your programme new memory pages, those will be zero'd [or possibly filled with a different pattern], so there's a good chance that `malloc`ed memory will contain all bits zero until you have `free`d and later `malloc`ed a bit so that [parts of] previously allocated blocks are reused. `calloc` initialises the allocated memory with zeros.

Comment: And now my comment looks odd, with the question it answers removed. I'll let it stand, however, it may still be useful for you.

Comment: @DanielFischer, sorry, I didn't want to delete it. That was accidentally...  Of couse it will be useful! It seems that the memory was allocated with zeros.. And now everyting is 'ok', thanx!

Comment: Ah, misclicked. No problem. I'm glad I left it then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function interface is inconsistent.

You don't need to have `L` and `R` as parameters as you create them from inside.

Having a `LRChannels` coming in is contraproductive as well.

The easiest design would probably be

```
struct LandR_8 sepChannels_8( unsigned char *smp, unsigned long N)
{
    unsigned char *L;
    unsigned char *R;
    struct LandR_8 LRChannels;

    int i;

    L = malloc(N / 2);
    R = malloc(N / 2);

    for ( i = 0; i < (N / 2) ; i++ )    // separating
    {
        L[i] = smp[2 * i + 0];
        R[i] = smp[2 * i + 1];
    }

    // L and R don't need `free()`.

    LRChannels.L = L;
    LRChannels.R = R;
    return LRChannels;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You return the `LRChannels` parameter, but you never modify it, so if `LRChannels.L` was `NULL` when the function was called, you will have `LRC_8.L == NULL` after the assignment.

There is more wrong with the function:

```
struct LandR_8 sepChannels_8( unsigned char *smp, unsigned char *L, unsigned char *R,
                              unsigned long N, struct LandR_8 LRChannels )
{
    int i;

    L = malloc(N / 2);
    R = malloc(N / 2);
```

C is a pass-by-value language, so the two pointers `L` and `R` in the function are *copies* of the arguments passed. Any changes you make to these parameters are not visible outside the function. You `malloc` memory for them

```
    for ( i = 0; i < (N / 2) ; i++ )    // separating
    {
        L[i] = smp[2 * i + 0];
        R[i] = smp[2 * i + 1];
    }
```

and fill it, but never use that in any other way. When the function returns, the allocated memory is no longer reachable, it is leaked. Since neither the pointers in the caller are changed nor the memory they point to, these two should not be arguments to the function at all - or, if you want to modify the pointers in the caller, you need to pass their addresses.

```
    // L and R don't need `free()`.

    return LRChannels;
}
```

`LRChannels` is the unmodified copy of the argument.

You probably intended something like setting the `L` and `R` members of `LRChannels` to `L` and `R` before returning,

```
LRChannels.L = L;
LRChannels.R = R;
return LRChannels;
```